# QPad64's (QInsightPad's) output window

Tags: kdb

How do I get the q script output to be displayed in QPad64's (QInsightPad's) output window. I am presently starting q and QPad 64 with the following .bat file :

```
set QHOME=C:\Q\q
set QINIT=C:\code\server.q
set PATH=%PATH%;%QHOME%;%QHOME%\w32
START C:\QInsightPad-2.2_FREE-x64\qpad64.exe
```

Result: q opens in cmd window, but all output from scipts run in Qpad show up there ( in cmd ) instead of in Qpad's output window. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Qpad isn't really designed to be used like that. You could redirect the stdout and read it in to view in qpad.

```
\1 qproc.log
```

Your scripts could then have output to the log as certain things are done like so:

```
1"tables_loaded"
// \n for new line
1"\nfuncs_loaded"

read0 `:qproc.log

"tables_loaded"
"funcs_loaded"
```